Laravel API call to another docker container puts other internal API calls on pending state
I have a laravel application(front-end) running on a docker container that calls an API that is on another container (nodejs). The API call is working fine, however, the response takes some time around 20 seconds which is ok as the request does some data parsing. What's not ok is that while this request is in progress. Other API calls within the same Laravel app are in pending state too until the API call to the nodejs container is completed.
I am using nginx to map both the container using proxy_pass.
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 75 60;
    keepalive_requests 100;

    # upstream chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT} {
        # server nginx:80;
        # server chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT};
    # }

    # upstream docker-apache {
        # server apache:80;
    #}

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        # server_name micropak-preprod.sparktechstaging.com;
        location / {
           # proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx;
           proxy_pass           http://chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT};
           # proxy_redirect     off;
           # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name micropak-preprod.sparktechstaging.com;

        #root /var/www/html/public/micropak-frontend;
        #root /var/www/html/public;
        #index index.php index.htm index.html;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        index index.php;

        location / {
            # proxy_pass         http://docker-apache;
            # resolver           127.0.0.11;
            # resolver           8.8.8.8;
            # root /var/www/html/public;
            # root /var/www/public;
            proxy_pass             http://micropak:${CHAT_FRONTEND_PORT};
            proxy_connect_timeout  180s;
            proxy_send_timeout     180s;
            proxy_read_timeout     180s;
            proxy_http_version     1.1;
            proxy_set_header       Connection '';
            proxy_set_header       Host $host;
            proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            # proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-proto $scheme;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass app:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = 128M";
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
}

}

Could this be related to php-fpm max_children settings? if yes how can I configure this in the dockerfile?
DockerFile:
FROM node:16.0.0 AS node
FROM php:8.1-fpm
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    zip \
    curl \
    unzip \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-source delete

# Copy application files (including composer.json)
COPY . /var/www/html

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN  npm i -f
RUN npm run build
RUN composer install
RUN composer update

# Set directory permissions
RUN mkdir -p storage
RUN mkdir -p bootstrap/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/storage \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 9000
EXPOSE 9000

# Start PHP-FPM server
CMD ["php-fpm"]

